# Project a list of of property values in Gremlin (Cosmos)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am storing multiple values in a gremlin vertex property. Now i want to return all the values of that property in a query.

> g.AddV('test').property('id','1').property(list,'name','name1')
>
> g.V('1').property(list,'name','name2')
>
> g.V('1').property(list,'name','name3')

When i do `g.V('1')` i get below response.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "label": "test",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "name": [
        {
          "id": "de80d819-91ca-4b28-8623-aadf652f0afb",
          "value": "name1"
        },
        {
          "id": "45fd395c-265e-448a-bdbd-7af9b1a3ce57",
          "value": "name2"
        },
        {
          "id": "23a1ee04-0113-4da1-9703-1e9a4f3033e8",
          "value": "name3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now i want to return only values of `name` property and `id`. Expected result should be as follows

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "names: : [
         "name1",
         "name2",
         "name3"
   ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`g.V('1').valueMap(true, 'name')`

And also this one:

```
g.V('1').project('id', 'names')
    .by(id())
    .by(values('name').fold())
```